# blockUI is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I have folowing code where i am using block ui,but its not blocking the page.i am using ajax call to get user control result (partial view) to load into div in page.during ajax call i want to block the complete page using blockui.

```
 $('#btnGO').click(function() {


        if (validate()) {
            alert("loading");
            $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>' }); //this is not working

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Controller/action/", //to get the partial view
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert("ajax complete event")
                    $.unblockUI(); 
                },

                data: $('#frmPassBook').serialize(),
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    $('#ErrorMessage').html(xhr.responseText);
                    $("#ErrorMessage").stop().show('slow');
                    $('#ui-widget').show();
                    $.unblockUI();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#aCBDetails").parent().show();
                    $("#divCBDetails").hide("blind");
                    $("#aCBDetails span:first").removeClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-n").addClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-s");
                    $('#ui-widget').hide();
                   //loading html in div
                   $("#div").html(data);

if ($("#rbMain") != undefined) {

                        if ($("#rbMain").attr("checked")) {
                            $(".subTrId").hide();
                            $("#spSub").hide();
                            $("#spMain").show();

                        }
                        else {
                            $(".subTrId").show();
                            $("#spSub").show();
                            $("#spMain").hide();

                        }
                    } else {

                        $("#spSub").show();
                        $("#spMain").hide();
                    }

//unblocking after div is loaded with html
                   $.unblockUI();
                }
            });
        } else {

           $.unblockUI();

        }
        return false ;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **baseZ** index to block the whole page
eg.

```
$.blockUI({ 
                                            message: "<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>",
                                            baseZ: 9000,
                                            css: { 
                                                top:  ($(window).height() - 400) /2 + "px", 
                                                left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + "px", 
                                                width: "400px"} 
});
```

Comment: applied this as  $.blockUI({ 
            message: '<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>', 
             baseZ: 9000,
                                            css: { 
                                                top:  ($(window).height() - 400) /2 + "px", 
                                                left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + "px",
                                                width: "400px"
                                            }
                      }); but its not working sorry..

Comment: Why did you accept this answer if it wasn't what helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` methods of jQuery. These will enable you to apply loader as ajax call starts and remove it as it ends.

Comment: Instead of using another plugin to block the UI, the easier thing can be binding ajaxStart and ajaxStop that are provided by default in jquery.

Comment: thanks for all the responses but when i comment out  async: false its working !!!

Comment: I had a similar problem.  The reason commenting out async: false works is likely because it was calling unblock immediately after calling block whilst asynchronously waiting for the ajax call to complete.  Commenting out async: false would have made the ajax call perform synchronously so the processing would stop and wait for the ajax call to return before the unblock was performed.