# GIF Image is not animating in Firefox and IE Browser using blockUI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

gif image is not animating in Firefox(21.0) and IE(All Versions) Browsers  while redirecting the page.The following code i'm using in usercontrol

```
<form method="post" name="frmhotelsearch" onsubmit="ShowProgress()" id="frm_<%=(int)Model.SearchProductType%>_Search" action="/Product/ProductResults">
```

-----Form code here----

```
</form>
```

jquery function  :

```
var myPicProgress = new Image();
myPicProgress.src = "../../Frontend/b2b/images/busy.gif";

function ShowProgress() 
{
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src=' + myPicProgress.src + ' />' + 'Just a Moment' + '</h1>', showOverlay: false }).on('beforeload', function () { $.blockUI(); });
}
```

Please give a suitable idea for this issue. i have wasted lots of time for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many known issues with ie and block UI not working.

```
It's a known bug (limitation) of IE. You could use javascript to solve it. Just preload image and change source (<img src="?">) of freezing image to that preloaded image on "onbeforeunload" action
```

This link has many relevent answers to your question.
[bLock UI Stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping) and [Block UI not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142746/blockui-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The form is in the process of being submitted. All animations will stop. Just add a normal button:

```
<input type='button' id='btnSubmit' />
```

bind the `onclick` event, and then from onclick do:

```
..code to show the blockUI
$('form').submit();
```

or you can submit the form on the blockUI callback. I would personally not use any animation if the form is being submitted, if it does not take too long.

Answer (score 0):

The following was tested on:

1) Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17105

2) Firefox 30.0

3) Crome 35.0.1916.153

All of the above browsers were running on Windows 7 Professional (64 bit).

**The BlockUI Message Content**

```
<div id="busyMessage" name="busyMessage" hidden="hidden" style='margin:0 auto; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'>
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Busy.gif")" alt="I am busy..." id="busyImage" />
    <br/>
    <label style='font-size:24px;'>Working...</label>
</div>
```

**The JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Preserve the original image source.
    var originalSource = $('#busyImage').attr('src');

    //Reset the current image source.
    $('#busyImage').attr('src', originalSource + "?" + new Date().getTime());

    $.blockUI({ css: {
                border: 'none',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: .5,
                color: '#fff',
                baseZ: 9000
                },
                message: $('#busyMessage')
                    });
});
```